# Boost deadline_timer does not get called on expiry

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I tried a simple boost asio timer example which checks the current minute and schedules a callback the next minute, but strangely, the call back never happens even though the expiry time printed out was clearly correct.

Any one can offer pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

```
void on_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    std::cout << "timer expired current time : " << microsec_clock::local_time() << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    auto today = day_clock::local_day();
    auto local_time = microsec_clock::local_time();
    auto hh         = local_time.time_of_day().hours();
    auto mm         = local_time.time_of_day().minutes();

    auto new_duration = hours(hh) + minutes(mm + 1);
    auto expiry = ptime(today, new_duration);
    // Set an expiry time relative to now.

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_context);
    timer.expires_at(expiry);
    std::cout << "current time : " << local_time << std::endl;
    std::cout << "expires " << to_simple_string(timer.expires_at()) << std::endl;

    // Wait for the timer to expire.
    timer.async_wait(on_timeout);

    io_context.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more fiddling around I realised that it's a time-zone issue. Everything needs to be in UTC it seems.